# zlib - Zero compression rate for gzip

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I have the following C++ code which uses zlib to compress a memory
buffer into a gzip encoded stream:

```
void compress(const std::vector<char>& src)
{
    static constexpr int DEFAULT_WINDOW_BITS = 15;
    static constexpr int GZIP_WINDOW_BITS = DEFAULT_WINDOW_BITS + 16;
    static constexpr int GZIP_MEM_LEVEL = 8;

    z_stream stream;

    const auto srcData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(src.data()));

    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    stream.next_in = srcData;
    stream.avail_in = src.size();

    auto result = deflateInit2(&stream,
                               Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
                               Z_DEFLATED,
                               GZIP_WINDOW_BITS,
                               GZIP_MEM_LEVEL,
                               Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);

    if (result == Z_OK)
    {
        std::vector<char> dest(deflateBound(&stream, stream.avail_in));
        const auto destData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(dest.data());

        stream.next_out = destData;
        stream.avail_out = dest.size();

        result = deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);

        if (result == Z_STREAM_END)
        {
            std::cout << "Original: " << src.size() << "; compressed: " << dest.size() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Error when compressing: code " << std::to_string(result);
        }

        result = deflateEnd(&stream);

        if (result != Z_OK)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: Cannot destroy deflate stream: code " << std::to_string(result) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Cannot initialize deflate stream: code " << std::to_string(result) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

While the function finishes successfully, I'm getting no compression
at all. In fact, for a 3MB file consisting of just the character 'a'
repeated multiple times, I get the following:

```
Original: 3205841; compressed: 3206843
```

Am I doing something wrong?

(Notice that this is a simplified version of the original code; in practice, I'd be using RAII and exceptions for resource and error handling).

Comment: Why are you using `dest.size()` instead of `stream.total_out`?

Comment: Oh, darn.. you're right, that does show a smaller size. However, why does deflateBound give such a large number to begin with?

Comment: "The deflateBound() and compressBound() functions can be used to provide an upper limit on the expansion in order to permit the allocation of an output buffer assured to be large enough to hold the entire compressed output." - upper limit = worst case

Comment: if you want to see the worst case in action, use random or encrypted data as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on the question are the answers, so just to record them here for posterity ...

`dest.size()` does not, and cannot be changed by `deflate()`. All you get from `dest.size()` is the size of your output buffer *before* compression. You need to look at *something* that comes back from the `deflate()` call in order to determine the size of the compressed result. That can be either `dest.size() - strm.avail_out`, or `strm.total_out`.

Doing the compression in a single call means that you need to fit both the input and output buffer sizes in an `unsigned`, which is usually 32 bits. So you are limited to compressing about 4 GB of data. If you might need to do more, then you would need a loop, calling `deflate()` for smaller chunks. Possibly much smaller chunks, measured in 10's or 100's of Kbytes. That is the usual way to use `deflate()`, since it takes much less memory and keeps your routine from being a resource hog in that regard.

`deflateBound()` is specifically for the purpose of supporting the use of a single `deflate()` call. It provides an upper bound on the possible compressed size, which can be a smidge *larger* than the input data. That is the case when the input data is incompressible, e.g. already compressed or random.